# Multi Independent Api Call With CompletableFuture Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to make multiple calls async in my Java project;

```
   List<CompletableFuture<Response>> postControlList = List.of(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> controller.independentTask1(item), executor)
                , CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> controller.independentTask2(item), executor)
                , CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> controller.independentTask3(item), executor)
        );
        controller.checkFutureList(holder, postControlList);
```

And checkFutureList Method ;

```
   public void checkFutureList(Object item, List<CompletableFuture<Response>> futureList) {

    for (var future : futureList) {
        var response = future.join();
        if (!response.isSuccess()) {
            item.setResponse(response);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Am i using it in a right way? Or should i make some updates for performance boosting ?